# Verify AlertDialog shown on invalid text input

Tags: android, testing

I am writing tests for an android application by using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. And I would like to verify that an AlertDialog is shown when the input for an EditText is invalid.

The documentation says:

```
You can also verify that the Activity responds to invalid input by setting error messages in the View.
```

http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/guide/topics/testing/activity_testing.html

I think this is what I need. But I can't find how. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.

First of all I downloaded [Robotium](http://www.robotium.org).

After that I checked whether the AlertDialog is shown by checking the text it contains:

```
    public void testEnterNumberEditBoxForInvalidNumber() {
    solo.enterText(0, "1234567890123456");
    solo.clickOnImageButton(0);
    boolean actual = solo.searchText("The number entered is not valid.");

    assertEquals(true, actual);

}
```

I'm open to better solutions. That's why I won't mark the question checked for a while.